# Manually updating planner statistics

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

We have a severe misprediction of cardinality of some columns on some tables in our system after running ANALYZE (the tables in question have hundreds of millions to billions records). Increasing statistics target to the max = 10000 helps only a little. It seems in our case we can't make it work with acceptable accuracy using regular Postgres mechanisms,  because of our data distribution and probabilistic sampling of Postgres.
We could in theory collect n_distinct and mcv values ourselves, the overhead on that may be acceptable. The question is, would it be ok to update pg_statistic, pg_statistic_ext and pg_statistic_ext_data manually? Are there any known side effects of that?
P.S. I'm aware that we can set n_distinct on the columns through ALTER TABLE, but collection of mcv values will still be on Postgres.

Comment: You can try extended statistics with `CREATE STATISTICS`. But without seeing `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for your actual query, I cannot say anything definitive.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yeah, we have a bunch of extended statistics objects as well. It helped tangentially, but didn't solve the problem. Also, it's not just one query, it's across the board problem. The problem is our queries typically have 6-7 joins and depending on input the plans should be pretty different. The queries work mostly pretty well (for > 90% of input parameters, but for a small percentage we get very inefficient execution plans).

Comment: I see only 2 ways in this situation actually. Initially I thought it may be possible to collect more accurate statistics than postgres, hence the question above. Although I found that pg_statistic can't be updated because of anyarray data type for which updates are forbidden, so that's probably out of the question already. Another one is to basically implement our own planner, i.e. based on our own app-collected statistics force optimizer to choose this or that execution plan using pg_hint_plan and enabling/disabling optimizer features. This seems ugly, but it might work...

Comment: As I said, without seeing a typical example, it is hard to give advice. The problem could also be your data model.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe That would be a long discussion not well suitable for stackoverflow. Assuming the problem is in insufficient accuracy of statistics that Postgres can generate (I have a good evidence of that, i.e. even for n_distinct calculated manually vs by ANALYZE I sometimes see an order of magnitude differences) . It's a well known issue for large datasets. What do you think could be realistic solutions? I'm asking in general, of course if we get into the details there could be something more suitable for our case. But I'm curious if there are any general ideas I'm not familiar with.

Comment: "It's a well known issue for large datasets": I have never heard of it before. I have never seen a case of PostgreSQL getting the statistics wrong all over the place.

Comment: Well, believe it or not, I'm facing this problem right now. And I heard about cases like that (well, I specifically searched for them as I got the same issue). Here is one example (and a proposed solution) - https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1548191628417-0.post%40n3.nabble.com. There are much older discussions in postgres mailing lists (20 years old or something) about viability of random sampling in general. I tried to work in that direction mentioned by the link above, but the solution proposed is still not good enough IMO, because mcv data cannot be modified this way, only n_distinct.

Comment: I had a look at that message. It seems to be about `n_distinct`, which indeed is known to be hard to get right (and which you consequently can override).

Comment: But that's exactly about "getting statistics wrong all over the place". n_distinct influences how most common values are calculated. But, as I said, it's not an ideal solution anyway. You can override it, and it will in turn make mcv lists a bit more accurate, but since it's still sampling a small portion of the data, it won't get those values right.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to override the statistics PostgreSQL collects, with the exception of `n_distinct`, which can be set with `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ... SET (n_distinct = ...)`. You can update `pg_statistic` if you are a superuser, but the data types used might require that you use a C function. Also, updating catalog tables is not supported and not a good solution here, because these statistics are lost during an upgrade or whenever autovacuum decides to `ANALYZE` the table.

Comment: If you effectively collect your own statistics, autoanalyze can be turned off, that shouldn't be an issue. Upgrade could be an issue, but that's an issue in any case... But yes, it seems it's not possible to update pg_statistic by conventional means...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I've found a way to do that (by looking at some abandoned extension of Postgres Pro - https://github.com/postgrespro/postgrespro/tree/DEV/contrib/dump_stat). The way to write into `anyarray` columns is to utilize some obscure function called `array_in`. It's very underdocumented, I'd say, only mentioned in Postgres documentation once, but it can do the trick.